# Is there any rules or document to help reading rabiitmq log?

Tags: rabbitmq

```
2019-01-20 03:38:19.175 [error] <0.4626.1207> ** Generic server <0.4626.1207> terminating
** Last message in was {inet_async,#Port<0.17388085>,78,{ok,<<50,20,0,15,104,98,47,48,48,48,51,48,48,48,48,48,48,50,55,20,63,97,16,42,0,4,77,81,84,84,4,194,0,250,0,12,48,48,48,51,48,48,48,48,48,48,50,55,0,6,115,101,110,115,111,114,0,8,106,75,103,54,100,102,55,56>>}}
** When Server state == {state,#Port<0.17388085>,"223.104.255.194:27961 -> 192.168.1.142:1883",true,undefined,true,running,{none,<0.28431.1206>},<0.2704.1201>,false,none,{proc_state,#Port<0.17388085>,#{},{undefined,undefined},{0,nil},{0,nil},10,1,"000300000027",true,undefined,{<0.18944.1195>,<0.6981.1202>},<0.30090.1204>,<<"amq.topic">>,{amqp_adapter_info,{0,0,0,0,0,65535,49320,398},1883,{0,0,0,0,0,65535,57192,65474},27961,<<"223.104.255.194:27961 -> 192.168.1.142:1883">>,{'MQTT',"N/A"},[{variable_map,#{<<"client_id">> => <<"000300000027">>}},{channels,1},{channel_max,1},{frame_max,0},{client_properties,[{<<"product">>,longstr,<<"MQTT client">>}]},{ssl,false}]},none,<0.16958.0>,{auth_state,<<"sensor">>,{user,<<"sensor">>,[management],[{rabbit_auth_backend_internal,none}]},<<"ningxiang">>},#Fun<rabbit_mqtt_processor.0.96330891>},<0.30090.1204>,{state,fine,5000,#Ref<0.3694003617.3118202884.104013>}}
** Reason for termination == 
** {function_clause,[{rabbit_mqtt_processor,process_login,[<<"sensor">>,<<"jKg6df78">>,4,{proc_state,#Port<0.17388085>,#{},{undefined,undefined},{1,{10,5183,nil,nil}},{0,nil},11,1,"000300000027",true,undefined,{<0.18944.1195>,<0.6981.1202>},<0.30090.1204>,<<"amq.topic">>,{amqp_adapter_info,{0,0,0,0,0,65535,49320,398},1883,{0,0,0,0,0,65535,57192,65474},27961,<<"223.104.255.194:27961 -> 192.168.1.142:1883">>,{'MQTT',"N/A"},[{variable_map,#{<<"client_id">> => <<"000300000027">>}},{variable_map,#{<<"client_id">> => <<"000300000027">>}},{channels,1},{channel_max,1},{frame_max,0},{client_properties,[{<<"product">>,longstr,<<"MQTT client">>}]},{ssl,false}]},none,<0.16958.0>,{auth_state,<<"sensor">>,{user,<<"sensor">>,[management],[{rabbit_auth_backend_internal,none}]},<<"ningxiang">>},#Fun<rabbit_mqtt_processor.0.96330891>}],[{file,"src/rabbit_mqtt_processor.erl"},{line,473}]},{rabbit_mqtt_processor,process_request,3,[{file,"src/rabbit_mqtt_processor.erl"},{line,112}]},{rabbit_mqtt_processor,process_frame,2,[{file,"src/rabbit_mqtt_processor.erl"},{line,69}]},{rabbit_mqtt_reader,process_received_bytes,2,[{file,"src/rabbit_mqtt_reader.erl"},{line,270}]},{gen_server2,handle_msg,2,[{file,"src/gen_server2.erl"},{line,1050}]},{proc_lib,wake_up,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,257}]}]}
2019-01-20 03:38:19.175 [error] <0.4626.1207> CRASH REPORT Process <0.4626.1207> with 0 neighbours exited with reason: no function clause matching rabbit_mqtt_processor:process_login(<<"sensor">>, <<"jKg6df78">>, 4, {proc_state,#Port<0.17388085>,#{},{undefined,undefined},{1,{10,5183,nil,nil}},{0,nil},11,1,"0003...",...}) line 473 in gen_server2:terminate/3 line 1166
2019-01-20 03:38:19.176 [error] <0.1769.1200> Supervisor {<0.1769.1200>,rabbit_mqtt_connection_sup} had child rabbit_mqtt_reader started with rabbit_mqtt_reader:start_link(<0.2704.1201>, {acceptor,{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},1883}, #Port<0.17388085>) at <0.4626.1207> exit with reason no function clause matching rabbit_mqtt_processor:process_login(<<"sensor">>, <<"jKg6df78">>, 4, {proc_state,#Port<0.17388085>,#{},{undefined,undefined},{1,{10,5183,nil,nil}},{0,nil},11,1,"0003...",...}) line 473 in context child_terminated
2019-01-20 03:38:19.176 [error] <0.1769.1200> Supervisor {<0.1769.1200>,rabbit_mqtt_connection_sup} had child rabbit_mqtt_reader started with rabbit_mqtt_reader:start_link(<0.2704.1201>, {acceptor,{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},1883}, #Port<0.17388085>) at <0.4626.1207> exit with reason reached_max_restart_intensity in context shutdown
```

So what does it mean?or any rules or document to help reading this?

Answer (score 0):

You have a crash report. The crash reason is given in the third line from the bottom:

> Process <0.4626.1207> with 0 neighbours exited with reason: no function clause matching rabbit_mqtt_processor:process_login( ...

Now, I have no idea what you were trying to do, but if that helps you get a little bit further along, then great!  Usually when a process crashes like this, it's because of an attempt to access an uninitialized memory address, which in and of itself is an error with the executing code (in this case, likely a failure to guard inputs to an external interface).